# Official angular google map component is not showing map

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps

I am trying to use the new google map component from the Angular Team (from package `@angular/google-maps`) by following this [tutorial](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/google-maps-as-an-angular-component).

For some reason the map is not showing and i can only see a grey square

If I create the map directly without the angular component using a simple div for the map, it works fine.

I have reproduced the issue in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jqnvuo)

Any idea what I could be doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: you don't seem to be pulling the script with your API key

Comment: setting the key results with the same issue (I have tried that). Omitting the key should result in the map with a extra 'For development purpose only' overlay as displayed on the regular map (the one not using the angular map component)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out that there is an [issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/18951) with the version 9.2.0 of the `"@angular/google-maps"` package. I tried with version 9.1.3 and it works fine.